# LaTex document does not show up correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

I am following an example for LaTex documentation in markdown and it begins with the following :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
Hello, \LaTeX! 
\end{document}
```

when I run the cell, I expect to see Hello, LaTeX! but instead it renders to:

[image]

I should mention i only have problem with the document style; `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` works fine and it renders to the expected equations.

Comment: Directly using $$\LaTeX! $$ for newline, inline $\LaTeX! $. `Hello $\LaTeX$`, nothing else is needed.

Comment: I agree, just typing in the markdown cell, renders to the text but with no style.   My question is why \begin{document} does not work

Comment: MathJax powers notebook, that's how it process.